# what is the minimum configuration required to do a Hadoop Proof of Concept in Cloud?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am looking for so guidance and tips in understanding what would it take to do a reasonable Hadoop Proof of Concept in the Cloud? I am a complete noob to the Big Data Analytics world and I will be more than happy for some suggestions that you might have based on your experience?

Comment: You should probably take a look at Amazon's Elastic-Mapreduce (http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/): move some data to an S3 bucket, launch a cluster, and then do whatever you want (e.g. Hive, Pig, write your own MapReduce). That's probably the shortest path to Hadoop: you can be up and running very quickly indeed!

Comment: You should probably take a look at [Microsoft's HDInsight](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/hdinsight/): move some data to an Azure Blob storage account, launch a cluster, and then do whatever you want( e.g. Hive, Pig, write your own MapReduce, use C#).

Answer (score 0):

Step by step guide to create HDFS cluster and start using it.
Hope it helps you.
http://www.edureka.co/blog/install-apache-hadoop-cluster/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, there are two important pieces:

1. Setting up a hadoop cluster requires installing some sort of hadoop distibution (apache open source or cloudera or IBM). This would give you the opportunity to learn about Hadoop configuration, space allocation, performance and all type of administration for your cluster. 
   To do this, you need your own hardware/cloud and install any of the above mentioned hadoop distribution yourself.
2. Secondly, you would want to learn about map reduce framework and multiple hadoop components like hive, hbase etc.
   To do this, you can go to [Bluemix](https://ace.ng.bluemix.net/?cm_mmc=dw-_-bluemix-_-biginsightsquick-dl-_-tile) 
   Its a good place to start hadoop on cloud service.

Both these skills are important and required to work with hadoop.